# R Subset Data from Spatialdataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, spatial, adehabitathr

I am trying to analyze spatial data in R. I ran into problems trying to subset my data for the analysis. First of all my raw data had this format. The Dataframe is called "locs":

```
  AnID      X          Y
1 Ind7   408046.3   5508986
2 Ind7   407445.4   5508927
3 Ind7   407588.2   5508927
4 Ind7   407595.9   5508819
5 Ind7   408079.9   5508904
```

It contains the coordinates for seven different animals (Ind1-Ind7). When i turned it into SpatialPointsDataFra‌​‌​‌me and used the `head(locs)` command I got this:

```
  AnID
1 Ind7
2 Ind7
3 Ind7
4 Ind7
5 Ind7
6 Ind7
```

So as you can see all the coordinates are gone. I try to subset the data so that only the rows of Ind3 are available.

```
Animal3 <- locs[as.data.frame(locs)[,1]=="Ind3",]
```

When i plot this data i can see all 75 locations perfectly but when i use the following command i get an error:

```
kernelUD(Animal3, h=293, grid=ab)
```

The error says:

```
Error in `kernelUD(Animal3, h = 293, grid = ab)` : 
  At least 5 relocations are required to fit an home range
```

Comment: please provide the actual data you're using. You mentioned you have a data frame but from the sounds of it, you don't. what does ``class(loc)`` spit out at you?

Comment: After i turned my raw data into SpatialPointsDataFrame. Class() gives out 1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"attr(,"package")[1] "sp" for both.

Comment: SpatialPointsDataFra‌me? or Spatialpixeldataframe????

Comment: also it would help to provide actual data and full workflow....

Comment: `> locs <- read.csv2("C:/Users/xxxDesktop/rcsv/locs.csv")
>  View(locs)
> coordinates(locs) <- c("X", "Y")
> proj4string(locs) <- CRS("+init=epsg:3044")
> class(locs)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
> Animal3 <- locs[as.data.frame(locs)[,1]=="Ind3",]
> Animal3
            coordinates AnID
274 (408562.2, 5509339) Ind3
275 (408535.4, 5509348) Ind3
276 (408532.7, 5509341) Ind3
277 (408518.6, 5509318) Ind3
278 (408518.4, 5509356) Ind3
279 (408518.6, 5509394) Ind3
280   (408549, 5509418) Ind3
281 (408573.8, 5509391) Ind3`

Comment: > class(Animal3)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
`> kernelUD(Animal3, h = 293, grid = 60)
Error in kernelUD(Animal3, h = 293, grid = 60) : 
  At least 5 relocations are required to fit an home range` The raw data is totally like show in my first post with 403 rows and 3 columns. The problem must come from the subsetting. I guess

Comment: please post reproducible data if you want help on stack overflow. we don't have access to your local hard drive!! also you said SpatialPointsDataFra‌me in your comment but on the post you said Spatialpixeldatafram‌e

Comment: It is SpatialPointsDataFra‌​‌me. I made a mistake in my first post. How do I attach my data? Comments only allow limited characters?

Comment: re edit your original post, but thats besides the point. ``locs <- read.csv2("C:/Users/‌​xxxDesktop/rcsv/locs.‌​csv") `` is meaningless to us, we don't have access to your hard. either recreate the data in line, produce similar data as an example, or post a link to the data.

Comment: and why mention Indy 1-7 when your example has only Indy1? also its impossible that ``head(lots)`` produced what you say it produced ``head()`` only spits out the first 5 rows...

Comment: Also X and Y don't look like coordinates to me...

Comment: Please use `dput(locs)` to and add the result to your question. Otherwise, we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: they are utm. when i load in dataframes containing only one animal at a time it works. so i guess it can only be me subsetting the data wrong. i'll try to work around